# Alternative list-comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I came across a question were someone wanted to generate `list3 = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]` for `list1 = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1`] and `list2 = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]`.

If one would `zip(list1, list2)` therefore only `zip(0, 0)` would generate `1` for `list3`.

I want to express the subsequent code by a list comprehension:

```
L3 = []
for x in zip(L1, L2):
    if sum(x) == 0:
        L3.append(1)
    else:
        L3.append(0)
print L3
```

I can get the same output by using this list comprehension:

```
print [int(sum(x)==0) for x in zip(L1, L2)]
```

I would like to know if there is a way to express the if/else condition of the initial code block in a list comprehension more literally. I can understand this question might be considered superfluous as the if/else condition naturally is comprised, but alternatives posted could be very useful to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a conditional expression:

```
print [1 if sum(x) == 0 else 0 for x in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Here, `1 if sum(x) == 0 else 0` directly expresses the condition.

For more information, see [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Another alternative is to factor out the logic into a function, and call the function from the list comprehension. This would allow the logic to use any flow control statements (conditional statements, loops etc).

Answer (score 1):

```
L1,L2 = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
# map and lambda 
L3 =  map(lambda x: 1 if not sum(x) else 0, zip(L1, L2))
print L3
# [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```